# Де ставити знак відсотків тут "40-70"

Tags: пунктуація, типографіка

Сьогодні довелось написати фразу: *відносна вологість 25%, а має бути 40%-70%*.

Але тут я не певен, що я правильно розставив знаки відсотків, можливо треба інакше

- 40-70%
- 40%-70%
- 40-70%%

Як правильно?

Comment: Довідник [Мільчина](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091464.html) наводить такий приклад: "Это составляет 60—80 % всей массы груза". Також там є розділ "6.4.2. Знаки №, %, §, ° в тексте".

Comment: @Artemix, пропоную послуговуватися словниками української мови. Орфографічні правила інших мов можуть суттєво відрізнятися від правил української.

Comment: @bytebuster Це не словник а довідник редактора і корректора. Такі речі не вказуються у орфографічних (і будь-яких інших) словниках. Це "типографіка".

Comment: ¡Пунктуаційні і типографічні правила також є мово-специфічними , @Artemix ! У тій же китайській відсотковий інтервал записується так: %40～70。 Або ще простіше: 百分之四十～七十。 І на тих територіях, про які йдеться у довіднику Мільчина, вже років через 25 записуватиметься так само. :)) (UPD, перепрошую, SE псує символ. Авжеж, має бути не тільда, а \0xFF5E).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одразу чесно скажу, не можу віднайти весь мережевного [ДСТУ](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8) на затвердженому іменці. Але деякі посилання на нього маються [на Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83).

> Відповідно до пункту 6.15 ДСТУ 3651.1-97 позначення одиниці треба розташовувати в одному рядку з числовим значенням величини, без перенесення на наступний рядок. Між числом і позначенням одиниці залишають проміжок. Тому потрібно писати 15 °C, 20 %, 130 К, 5 м.

Себто між числами та знаком [нерозривний проміж](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB).

Також зазначу вид вживу Вікіпедією проміжку чогось

> 1. Тире ставиться між двома чи кількома словами для позначення діапазону («від… до»):
>
>    - просторового: *Переліт Одеса — Київ; рухатись шляхом Львів — Київ — Харків*;
>    - часового: *Хрестові походи XI—XIII століть; План на січень — березень*;
>    - кількісного: *Рукопис обсягом десять — дванадцять сторінок* (те ж саме цифрами: *10—12*); *Вантаж масою 300—500 кілограмів*; *5—7-річна програма*.
>
> Якщо між двома числами, що стоять поруч, можна за змістом вставити не слова «від… до», а слово *або* (*чи*), то вони поєднуються дефісом: *Буде у відрядженні пʼять-шість днів* (але при цифровому позначенні ставиться тире: *5—6 днів*).
>
> 2. Тире ставиться між двома або кількома власними назвами, сукупністю яких називається вчення, теорія, науковий закон тощо: *закон Бойля — Маріотта*; *Матч «Динамо» — «Шахтар»*.
> 3. Тире ставиться між окремими словами для показу внутрішнього звʼязку між ними: *Конференція «Архітектура — людина — навколишнє середовище»*; *Учора — сьогодні — завтра*; *«Міс Усесвіт — 2006»*, *«Повернення Мухтара 1—2»*, але *«Мухтар-2»*.

Себто для точного *від чогось до чогось* є тире, а для неточності є дефіс.

Удвоєння знаків чи скорочень не зутрічав на затвердженому рівні чи як вживу. Тільки загальновідоме *рр.*, що, схоже, було скальковано з московського *гг.*. Тому правильно допустимо

> 40 % — 70 %
>   40—70 %

Другий спосіб краще з погляду обʼєму, тому використовують частіше. Також таке собі уникнення проблем двякості штибу *віднімання*, де вид числа обовʼязковий.

А ось щодо ДСТУ знакопису вельми слабкий, а мітка стоїть. Тому лиш зазначу, [деякі](//ilyabirman.ru/meanwhile/all/spaces/) пропонують зміну відстані між знаками чи розміру проміжа і так вживати. Себто зробити свій набір пояснених правил знакопису й слідувати їм.